# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(\varphi_1x)}x\frac{\sin\varphi_2x}x\cdots\frac{\sin\varphi_nx}x\frac{\sin(ax)}x\cos(a_1x)\cdots\cos(a_mx) \, dx$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

How to evaluate

$$ 
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\varphi_1x)}{x}\frac{\sin\varphi_2x}{x} \cdots \frac{\sin\varphi_nx}{x} \frac{\sin(ax)}{x}\cos(a_1x) \cdots \cos(a_mx) \, dx  \text{ ?}
$$

For small $n$ and $m$ it's simple (setting $\sin(kx)=\dfrac{e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx}}{2i}$ and using Jordan's lemma, but for arbitrary $n$ the calculation is too tedious. Surely there must be some nice trick here?
Thanks

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the $\phi_k, a_j?$

Comment: This is an exercise in Whittaker and Watson, page 122; under conditions they give the answer as the product of the $\phi_i$ (including $\phi_0:=a$). They ascribe the result to Stormer, Acta Mathematica XIX. See https://archive.org/stream/courseofmodernan00whit#page/122/mode/2up

Comment: @ancientmathematician Can you say what the conditions are?  I went to the link you posted, but the page is too dim for me to read.

Comment: @saulspatz if $\phi_1,\cdots,\phi_n$, $a_1,\cdots,a_m$ be real and $a$ be positive and $a > |\phi_1| + \cdots |\phi_n|+|a_1|+\cdots+|a_m|$.

Comment: @saulpatz yes sorry: $a> |\phi_1|+...+|\phi_n| + |a_1|+...+|a_n|$, with a positive and $\phi_i$, $a_i$ real!

Comment: @saulspatz, it's so dim I can't be sure and think I may have misread the answer anyway.I have certainly forgotten the $\pi/2$. The coefficients are all real, I think, and $a$ has to exceed the sum of the moduli of the other multipliers. I don't have hardcopy, sorry.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I have a hard copy ;-) BTW, the integral is $\frac{\pi}{2} \phi_1\cdots \phi_n$ assume above condition is satisfied.

Comment: @ancientmathematician   I found a copy that was easier to read at https://books.google.com/books?id=ULVdGZmi9VcC&q=122#v=snippet&q=122&f=false

Comment: Surely one considers $\int \frac{\sin(\varphi_1x)}{z}\frac{\sin\varphi_2z}{z} \cdots \frac{\sin\varphi_nz}{z} \frac{e^{i a z}}{z}\cos(a_1z) \cdots \cos(a_mz) \, dz$  taking as contour the usual upper half-plane semi-circle, with an indent at the origin. The condition given ensures that the integral round the big semi-circle goes to $0$, and Jordan's lemma gives the correct residue at the origin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We will assume the parameters $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n$, $a_1,\ldots, a_m$ satisfy
the condition given in page 122 of Whittaker and Waston's classic "A Course of Modern Analysis".

> $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n$, $a_1, \ldots, a_m$ are real, $a$ is positive and
>   $a > \sum_{p=1}^n |\phi_p| + \sum_{q=1}^m | a_q|$

Under this condition, the integral at hand evaluates to $\frac{\pi}{2}\prod_{p=1}^n \phi_p$.

We will further assume all $\phi_p \ne 0$. Otherwise, the integral trivially evaluates to zero.

When $\phi_p \ne 0$, the singularity of $\frac{\sin(\phi_p x)}{x}$ at $x = 0$ is removable, if we define the value of $\frac{\sin(\phi_p x)}{x}$ at $x = 0$ to be $\phi_p$, we will turn this into an entire function.

Let $f(x)$ be the product $\prod\limits_{p=1}^n\frac{\sin(\phi_p x)}{x}\prod\limits_{q=1}^m \cos(a_q x)$. With above interpretation in mind, this is an entire function in $x$. For large $z \in \mathbb{C}$, we can bound the growth
of $f(z)$ as
$$|f(z)| = O( e^{K|\Im z|} )\quad\text{ where }\quad K = \sum_{p=1}^n|\phi_p| + \sum_{q=1}^m|a_m|\tag{*1}$$

Notice $\frac{\sin(a x)}{x}$ is finite
at $x = 0$ and $f(x)$ is an even function in $x$. 
Our integral equals to

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\frac{\sin a x}{x} dx 
= \lim_{\substack{R\to\infty\\ \epsilon\to 0}}  \int_{\epsilon}^R f(x)\frac{\sin( a x)}{x} dx
= \frac12 \lim_{\substack{R\to\infty\\ \epsilon\to 0}} \left(
\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon} + \int_{\epsilon}^R\right) f(x)\frac{\sin(a x)}{x} dx
\\= \frac{1}{2i}
\lim_{\substack{R\to\infty\\ \epsilon\to 0}} \left(
\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon} + \int_{\epsilon}^R\right)
f(x)\frac{e^{iax}}{x} dx
$$
To evaluate this integral, consider following contour $C$ consists of 4 segments:

- a line segment from $-R$ to $-\epsilon$.
- $C_\epsilon$ a circular segment $\epsilon e^{i\theta}$ with $\theta$ from $\pi$ to $0$.
- a line segment from $\epsilon$ to $R$.
- $C_R$ a circular segment $R e^{i\phi}$ with $\phi$ from $0$ to $\pi$.

Since $C$ doesn't contain any singularity of the integrand, we have

$$\oint_C f(x)\frac{e^{iax}}{x} dx = 0
\implies
\left(
\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon} + \int_{\epsilon}^R\right)
f(x)\frac{e^{iax}}{x} dx
= -\left(
\int_{C_R} + \int_{C_\epsilon}\right)
f(x)\frac{e^{iax}}{x} dx
$$
Under the assumption $a > K = \sum_{p=1}^n|\phi_p| + \sum_{q=1}^m |a_q|$, 
the bound $(*1)$ tell us
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{C_R} f(x)\frac{e^{iax}}{x} dx = 0$$
Since $f(x)$ is regular near $x = 0$, as $\epsilon \to 0$, the integral over $C_{\epsilon}$ gives us $-\pi i = (-\frac12)(2\pi i)$ of the residue of $f(x) \frac{e^{iax}}{x}$ at $x = 0$ ($-\pi i$ instead of $\pi i$ because $\theta$ varies from $\pi$ to $0$). As a result, the integral at hand equals to

$$\frac{i}{2}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{C_\epsilon}f(x)\frac{e^{iax}}{x}dx = \frac{i}{2} (-\pi i) f(0) e^{i0} = \frac{\pi}{2}f(0) = \frac{\pi}{2} \prod_{p=1}^n \phi_p$$

Comment: Perfect:) Thanks

Comment: What a masterful demonstration

Comment: Excellent, @achille hui. But have you any idea why Whittaker and Watson chose to call the $\sin$ parameters $\phi_i$ but the $\cos$ ones $a_i$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Whittaker and Waston just follow what Carl Störmer does who attempt to generalize the formula $\frac{\phi}{2} = \frac{\sin\phi}{1} - \frac{\sin(2\phi)}{2} + \frac{\sin(3\phi)}{3} - \cdots$. Störmer seems to
have derived an identity in [Acta Math. xix](https://archive.org/stream/actamathematica10lefgoog#page/n320/mode/2up)

Comment: $$\begin{align}
\frac{\phi_1\cdots\phi_n}{2} =&\phantom{+} \frac{\sin\phi_1}{1}\frac{\sin\phi_2}{1}\cdots\frac{\sin\phi_n}{1}\cos\alpha_1\cos\alpha_2\cdots\cos\alpha_m\\
&- \frac{\sin 2\phi_1}{2}\frac{\sin 2\phi_2}{2}\cdots\frac{\sin 2\phi_n}{2}\cos 2
\alpha_1\cos 2\alpha_2\cdots\cos 2\alpha_m\\
&+ \frac{\sin 3\phi_1}{3}\frac{\sin 3\phi_2}{3}\cdots\frac{\sin 3\phi_n}{3}\cos 
3\alpha_1\cos 3\alpha_2\cdots\cos 3\alpha_m\\
&- \cdots\cdots
\end{align}
$$ Since I don't know German,  I can't tell exactly what happens.

Comment: It's French, but I can't see how his manipulation of these series relates to the integral. I suppose I could have asked my analysis prof, Copson, fifty years ago - he was Whittaker's son-in-law and proofread the first edition of W&W.

Comment: @achillehui That's french. You can ignore the text. My former advisor gave me some book in russian and he said "just ignore the text and read the formulas".

Comment: @ancientmathematician I think the idea is that you can use Carl Stoermer's series, let the argument be $(-1)^{n+1}f(n)/\pi,$ and evaluate it by the summing the residues of $\pi f(z)\csc\pi z$ at the poles of $f(z),$ which you can then show is equivalent to just doing the original integral.